# Is the iMessage small photo browser a standard iOS component?

Tags: ios, photos, imessage

In iOS 9 there's a new "quick-library" access to your latest photos. Is this a standard component that is documented, or does anyone know of any third party implementations?

[image: iOS 9 iMessage photo picker]

Comment: Just found [ImagePickerSheetController](https://github.com/larcus94/ImagePickerSheetController), a swift implementation. Would still love to hear if this is a standard component though.